# Crystal Reports Greater than or equal to parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I am relatively new to Crystal Reports, I have created the report which is all working fine put I want to added to parameters. The first is Customer where the user selects or Customer they want to run the report on, which is working fine.

The second is Delivery date which is what I am stuck on. I want to create a report parameter so that when the user selects the delivery date that it shows all results from the selected date to the current date.

For example:

User selects 01/01/2014 for Customer X : the query should return all deliveries from 01/01/2014 to the current date for customer X.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a Parameter `Start Date` with date datatype and in `record selection formula` write below code:

Assuming you have a date field in database:

```
tablename.date>={?Start Date} and tablename.date<CurrentDate
```

Comment: Hi Siva, thanks for your reply this works but I also sorted by using 
    {tblWJC.DespatchDate} >= {?Delivery Date} and
    {tblCustomer.CustomerName} = {?Customer}

Comment: is there any issue if you have added more sorting option? I didn't get your requirement?